# Generically-typed interface for which lambdas can be used?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm still new to lambda expressions, and I've been trying to practice with them in order to better understand how they work. I came across a pdf online with a few exercises to practice: http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/java/exercises/exercises-lambdas-1.pdf . I am on the last problem, and I am having difficulty understanding exactly what is needed to accomplish it.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    interface TwoElementPredicate <E>
{
    boolean betterCheck(E e1, E e2);
}

public class LambdaPractice4 <E>
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Car car1 = new Car(50);
        Car car2 = new Car(100);
        Employee worker1 = new Employee(500, "John");
        Employee worker2 = new Employee(1000, "Tom");
        String str1 = "String";
        String str2 = "SecondString";

        //These three lines do not work, due to duplicate variables. I thought lambdas were functions though?
        TwoElementPredicate<String> betterElement = (s1, s2) -> { return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
        TwoElementPredicate<Car> betterElement = (c1, c2) -> { return c1.getPrice() > c2.getPrice(); };
        TwoElementPredicate<Employee> betterElement = (w1, w2) -> w1.getSalary() > w2.getSalary(); //Trying different syntaxes

        /* These work, but instead of different ending arguments (betterCar, betterString, etc.) I want just one betterElement
        System.out.println(betterEntry(car1, car2, betterCar).getPrice());
        System.out.println(betterEntry(str1, str2, betterString));
        System.out.println(betterEntry(worker1, worker2, betterWorker).getName());
        */

        //This is what I would like to have to replace the three statements above
        System.out.println(betterEntry(car1, car2, betterElement));
        System.out.println(betterEntry(str1, str2, betterElement));
        System.out.println(betterEntry(worker1, worker2, betterElement));
    }

    public E betterEntry(E e1, E e2, TwoElementPredicate genericFace)
    {
        return genericFace.betterCheck(e1, e2) ? e1 : e2;
    }

    /*
    public static Car betterEntry(Car c1, Car c2, TwoElementPredicate genericFace)
    {
        return genericFace.betterCheck(c1, c2) ? c1 : c2;
    }

    public static Employee betterEntry(Employee e1, Employee e2, TwoElementPredicate genericFace)
    {
        return genericFace.betterCheck(e1, e2) ? e1 : e2;
    }

    public static String betterEntry(String s1, String s2, TwoElementPredicate genericFace)
    {
        return genericFace.betterCheck(s1, s2) ? s1 : s2;
    }
    */
}
```

The Employee and Car classes are defined underneath this code; they're not really relevant to the issues I'm having, but they do exist for those who were wondering.

Comment: What about this isn't working?  What error message do you get?

Comment: First, the three lines that I put a comment on saying "these lines do not work" give an error due to duplicate variables. Second, the three lines that I have put a comment on saying "this is what I would like to have..." give an error that says, "The method betterEntry(E, E, TwoElementPredicate) in the type LambdaPractice4<E> is not applicable for the arguments (Car, Car, TwoElementPredicate<Employee>)". I thought that E was supposed to be a placeholder for any given type though?

Comment: _What_ duplicate variables?  There is no other `s1` or `s2` or anything.  Or do you mean...multiple `betterElement` lambdas?  Why not just assign them to different variable names?  Lambdas are still variables.  What's wrong with `betterElementString` and `betterElementCar` and so on?

Comment: I could do that. In fact, I did at one point, and it worked. However, if you look at the last three lines of the problem that I'm working on (to which I posted the link) it seems like it wants the same function name to be able to handle any type. Presumably so that you could call the same function name no matter what type you were using. I have been unable to figure out if that's even possible, and if so, how to go about doing it.

Comment: Lambdas are not functions in _that_ way; they can't be overloaded.  There is no way to do what you want.  And the exercises there are 
_not_ saying you need to assign multiple lambdas of different types to the _same variable name._

Comment: What _would_ work would be something like `betterEntry(car1, car2, betterElementCar)` and have the three different lambdas, and only the one generic `betterEntry`.

Comment: Alright, so it's not possible and I just misunderstood the question. That does make it a lot easier then. In that case, does anyone know what the last three lines in the exercise I linked DO mean?

Comment: Nowhere in that exercise are the lambdas stored in a variable.  All you need is `public <E> E betterEntry(E e1, E e2, TwoElementPredicate<E> genericFace)`.  That's _it._

Comment: Thank you for your help.